# Sum() causes exception instead of returning 0 when no rows

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, nullreferenceexception

I have this code (ok, I don't, but something similar :p)

```
    var dogs = Dogs.Select(ø => new Row
    {
            Name = ø.Name,
            WeightOfNiceCats = ø.Owner
              .Cats
              .Where(æ => !æ.Annoying)
              .Sum(æ => æ.Weight),
    });
```

Here I go through all dogs and sum up the weight (into a non-nullable decimal) of all not-annoying cats which has the same owner as the dog. Of course, pretty much all cats are annoying, so I get this error:

> The null value cannot be assigned to a member with type System.Decimal which is a non-nullable value type.

None of the fields or foreign keys used can be null. So the error happens when the `Where` clause returns no cats, which it often does. But how can I solve this? I want it to return 0 when that happens. Tried with a `DefaultIfEmpty()` after the `Where` clause, but then I get this error:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Which I guess is understandable. I tried to add a `??` after the `Sum`, but then it wont compile because of this error:

> Operator '??' cannot be applied to operands of type 'decimal' and 'decimal'

Which also makes sense of course. So what can I do? Would be nice if the `Sum` thing just returned 0 when there was nothing to sum. Or a `SumOrZero` statement of some sort. Would it be difficult to make a `SumOrZero` method that worked with Linq2SQL?

Comment: Great question. It's a shame this behavior does not appear to be documented in the MSDN.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This is what I ended up with for now:

```
.Sum(æ => (decimal?) æ.Weight) ?? 0.0M,
```

This works like a charm.

I would still prefer to have a `SumOrZero` I could use, which would work exactly like the regular `Sum` except it would never return `null` for any reason. Like the others have noted, this would be pretty easy to make for `IEnumerable` but a bit more icky to create for `IQueryable` so it would work with Linq2SQL, etc. So I will just leave it at that for now. Although if someone is bored one day and do write a `SumOrZero` for `IQueryable` which works with Linq2SQL for all the numeric types, please do let me know :D

Comment: Small typo - there should be `decimal`*

Comment: @Daniel That is correct! And it only took 5 years for someone to notice and notify :p

Answer (score 5):

In LINQ to Objects it would be easy. With LINQ to SQL it will be harder. You could write your own extension method which called `Queryable.Sum` with an expression built up from the normal one, with a cast to the nullable type. I suspect you'd need to do the ?? 0m in the calling code though. In other words, you could do:

```
.SumOrNull(æ => æ.Weight) ?? 0M,
```

Where the signature for .SumOrNull would be:

```
public static decimal? SumOrNull<TSource, decimal>(this IQueryable<TSource>,
    Func<TSource,decimal> projection)
```

You could basically write that for all the value types supported in Queryable. You *could* write it generically, and call the appropriate method in Queryable using reflection, but that would be icky too.

I think you're best off with what you've got, to be honest.

Answer (score 3):

The trick you've already given (`.Sum(æ => (decimal?) æ.Weight) ?? 0.0M`) is about the best I can think of for this scenario when it executes as a query at the database. A bit annoying, but there are worse things...

Unlike LINQ-to-Objects, you can't just add your own extension method, as it needs to be mapped by the underlying provider.

Comment: exactly. that was what I feared, hehe.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use DefaultIfEmpty, which will return an IEnumberable with a single element of 0, and that will be semantically the same as you require.

As you have a nullable decimal, you will probably have to use the 2nd version of the method taking 2 parameters.

Comment: Quite the opposite; the decimal is non-nullable. The *workaround* to the LINQ-to-SQL glitch is to make it nullable for computation.

Comment: DefaultIfEmpty caused the "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Comment: Well figure out where your logic is wrong. Or better, post the broken code so we can see where you are going wrong. NullReferenceException is your fault 99% of the time.

Comment: um, what are you talking about? I have? Both the code, and the different error messages. Even the one you are talking about. Have you even read my question?

Comment: You are using it wrong...  You need to pass a non-null enumerable to DefaultIfEmpty, which you are not doing (hence the null exception). Not that hard, is it?